# GridLayout is showing odd behavior

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, grid-layout

I am trying to create a grid comprised of 100 squares. My code below is extremely buggy and I am not sure why.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;

public class snake extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Border whiteLine = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.white);
        //-----------FRAME
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(1000,1000);
        frame.setTitle("Snake");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));
        //-----------FRAME

        //-----------PANELS
        Dimension panelDimension = new Dimension(20,20);

        int counter = 0;
        JPanel[][] p = new JPanel[10][10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                p[i][j] = new JPanel();
                //p[i][j].setPreferredSize(panelDimension);
                p[i][j].setBackground(Color.red);
                //p[i][j].setLocation(490,490);
                p[i][j].setBorder(whiteLine);
                p[i][j].setVisible(true);

                frame.getContentPane().add(p[i][j]);

                counter+=1;
            }
        }
       System.out.println("counter: " + counter);


    }
}
```

When I run the code like this it shows a grid comprised of 2 columns the first column has 7 rows and the second column has 6. Sometimes it even shows other incorrect numbers of columns and rows. I am not sure why it doesn't create a grid of 10 rows 10 columns.

Comment: 1) Class names should start with an upper case character. 2) Don't extend JFrame, there is no need to extend any class. Your code creates an instance of JFrame so there is no need for two instances. 3) Swing components are visible by default, so no need to make the panel visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got several problems including:

- Calling `setVisible(true)` on the JFrame ***before*** adding components, before calling `pack()` on the top-level window. This can lead to wonky positioned components within our GUI's or even GUI's that remain empty
- Not calling `pack()` on the JFrame after adding components and before setting it visible
- Setting the size of the JFrame. Let the layout managers, containers and components do this for you (which is what calling `pack()` is for)
- Setting it to a bad size, a "perfect square", one that ignores the menu bar that the OS adds,
- ...

For example:

```
package foo01;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SnakePanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int CELL_WIDTH = 80;
    private static final Dimension CELL_DIMENSION = new Dimension(CELL_WIDTH, CELL_WIDTH);
    private static final int COLUMNS = 10;
    private static final int GAP = 2;
    private static final Color BG_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
    private static final Color CELL_COLOR = Color.RED;

    public SnakePanel() {
        setBackground(BG_COLOR);
        
        // add a white line around the grid
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        
        // create a grid with gaps that show the background (white) color
        setLayout(new GridLayout(COLUMNS, COLUMNS, GAP, GAP));

        for (int row = 0; row < COLUMNS; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++) {
                JPanel cell = new JPanel(); // create a new cell
                cell.setPreferredSize(CELL_DIMENSION); // cheating here. Better to override getPreferredSize()
                cell.setBackground(CELL_COLOR);
                add(cell);
                
                // give the cell JPanel some simple behavior:
                cell.addMouseListener(new MyMouse(col, row));
            }
        }
    }

    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        private int col;
        private int row;

        public MyMouse(int col, int row) {
            this.col = col;
            this.row = row;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.printf("Mouse pressed row and column: [%d, %d]%n", row, col);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            // create the main JPanel
            SnakePanel snakePanel = new SnakePanel();

            // create the JFrame
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Snake");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            
            // add the main JPanel to the JFrame
            frame.add(snakePanel);
            
            // pack the JFrame -- tells the layout managers to do their things
            frame.pack();
            
            // if we want to center the GUI:
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            
            // only *now* do we display the GUI
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Some notes on the code:

Any code within the Runnable passed into the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` method is called on the Swing event thread, which is a wise thing to do when creating a Swing GUI

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    // ....
});
```

First, create the main JPanel that is held by the JFrame:

```
SnakePanel snakePanel = new SnakePanel();
```

Then create the JFrame, add that JPanel and call `pack()`. The pack call tells the layout managers to do there thing, to lay out components within containers, to size things based on their preferred sizes and their layouts:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Snake");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add(snakePanel);
frame.pack();
```

if we want to center the GUI:

```
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

only *now* do we display the GUI

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I think making the frame.setVisible(true) the last piece of code fixed my problem. Pack also helped by enforcing my size of dimensions for panels. But for your method of creating the different cells there would be no way to change any detail about an individual cell from main correct?